# search only for streets with mklocalSearch swift

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am trying to query the `MapKit` about local addresses.

I am using the following functions :

```
localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = LuogoTextField.text
localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
```

`LuogoTextField.text` should contain the name of the street that the user is looking for.

My problem is that this query extracts also Points Of Interest and other activities. Is there a function or a way to query only the Streets ?

It is ok also if I have to change to google maps APIs.

Thanks